# Scrapy: next button uses javascript

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape from this website http://saintbarnabas.hodesiq.com/joblist.asp?user_id=
and I want to get all the RNs in it... I can scrape a data but cannot continue to the next page
because of its javascript. I tried reading to other questions but I don't get it. This is my code

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "commu"
    allowed_domains = ["saintbarnabas.hodesiq.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://saintbarnabas.hodesiq.com/joblist.asp?user_id=",
    ]
    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\d+'),restrict_xpaths=('*'))
    , callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    )
```

the next button shows as

```
<a href="Javascript: Move('next')">Next</a>
```

This pagination is kills me...

Comment: If you need to scrape JavaScript or AJAX content you can read it through Selenium WebDriver and Firefox which opens a full-blown browser to read the pages.

Comment: how? can you give me an idea so that it can direct to another page...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, you need to figure out what `Move('next')` does and reproduce that in your code.

A quick inspection of the sites shows that the function code is this:

```
function Move(strIndicator)
{
    document.frm.move_indicator.value = strIndicator;
    document.frm.submit();
}
```

And the `document.frm` is the form with name "frm":

```
<form name="frm" action="joblist.asp" method="post">
```

So, basically you need to build a request to perform the `POST` for that form with the `move_indicator` value as `'next'`. This is easily done by using the `FormRequest` class ([see the docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects)) like:

```
return FormRequest.from_response(response, formname="frm", 
                                 formdata={'move_indicator': 'next'})
```

This technique works in most cases. The difficult part is to figure out what does the javascript code, sometimes it might be obfuscated and perform overly complex stuff just to avoid being scraped.

Comment: I've written a BaseSpider using your answer at http://c9.io/redapple/so_18810850 . You're welcome to amend.

Comment: so where should I insert the something.select.something.extract()?

Comment: @chano The link just trigger the post in a form. The `FormRequest` parses the form in the page, loading the form's fields automatically, and constructs a request object. You don't need to `.extract()` anything else for this request.

Comment: I did try to run the code and I can see that it parse. But What I want to do is scrape some data.

Comment: Right, use the pattern `allow="JobID=\d+"` in your rule extractor and remove `the restrict_xpaths="*"`.